# `The foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed` in Phinx Migrations (CakePhp3)

Tags: php, cakephp, migration, cakephp-3.0, phinx

I have these two migration files, and I want to add the primary key of **"clients"** as a foreign key in **"samples"** but when migrating, it gives me an error that "The foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed".

Here is the screenshot of the command line:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Here is my code:

**CreateClients**

```
<?php
use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

class CreateClients extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function change()
    {
        $table = $this->table('clients');

        $table->addColumn('name', 'string', [
            'limit' => 100,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('title', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 100,
            'null' => true,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('street', 'string', [
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('city', 'string', [
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('state', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('zipcode', 'biginteger', [
            'limit' => 10,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('country', 'string', [
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('phone', 'biginteger', [
            'limit' => 10,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('emailprimary', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => true,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('emailsecondary', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => true,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('username', 'string', [
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => false,

        ])->addIndex(array('username'), array('unique' => true));
        $table->addColumn('password', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('billing_title', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => true,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('billing_street', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => true,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('billing_city', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => true,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('billing_state', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => true,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('billing_zipcode', 'biginteger', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 20,
            'null' => true,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('billing_country', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => true,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('billing_phone', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => true,
        ]);
        $table->create();
    }
}
```

**CreateSamples**

```
<?php
use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

class CreateSamples extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * Change Method.
     *
     * More information on this method is available here:
     * http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#the-change-method
     * @return void
     */
    public function change()
    {
        $table = $this->table('samples');

        $table->addColumn('name', 'string', [
            'limit' => '100',
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('client_id', 'integer', [
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addForeignKey('client_id', 'clients', 'id', array('delete'=> 'SET_NULL', 'update'=> 'NO_ACTION'));
        $table->save();

        $table->create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your CreateSamples migration, you define the `client_id` column as not null. However, when you define the foreign key, you do it as `on delete, set null`. That cannot go together. Instead of `SET_NULL`, `CASCADE` or `RESTRICT` would be a better choice, depending on the logic of your application. (Restrict would prevent you from deleting clients with samples.) You could also define the `client_id` column as `'null' => 'true'`.
So, for example, try this:

```
$table->addForeignKey('client_id', 'clients', 'id', array('delete'=> 'CASCADE', 'update'=> 'NO_ACTION'));
```

That will delete the samples when you delete the client.

More explanation about that MySQL's behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603449/mysql-foreign-key-on-delete-set-null-in-not-null-field).

Comment: If the referenced column is defined as 'NOT_NULL' SQL will not allow you to set it to null in a referencing column. 'RESTRICT' and 'CASCADE' will work perfectly but I would advice not to use 'CASCADE' in the case of 'delete'. It means that every time that you annihilate data in the parent column, you'll lose more data in the referencing tables without you noticing. Please use 'RESTRICT'